# how to replace question mark to word

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I have Arabic tweet and I want to replace question marks and exclamation into Arabic word synonymous I tried this code i used regular expression but nothing happens. I used jupyter notebook

```
def replace_questionmark(tweet):
text = re.sub("!", "تعجب",tweet)
text = re.sub('استفهام','؟' ,tweet)
return tweet

data_df['clean text'] = data_df['Text'].apply(lambda x: replace_questionmark(x))
```

Comment: works for me. Could you add an example of how it failed?

Comment: when i read the data it did not replace the marks

Comment: Please indent your code correctly and add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - something small that we can run and reproduce your problem.

Comment: You're passing `tweet` to `re.sub` and saving the returned string to `text` (twice) then you return the unchanged variable `tweet`. Try replacing `text` with `tweet`

Comment: yes, I replace text with tweet. it replaces only the "!" but "؟" did not replace. I do not know why.I think because of its Arabic marks, it did not recognize it ??

Answer (score 0):

The following code solves your problem

```
import pandas as pd
import re

Text = [u'I am feeling good !', u'I am testing this code ؟']
data_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Text'], data=Text)

def replace_questionmark(tweet):
    text = tweet.replace(u'!', u'تعج')
    text = text.replace(u'؟', u'استفهام')
    return text.encode('utf-8')

data_df['clean text'] = data_df['Text'].apply(lambda x: replace_questionmark(x))

print(data_df)
```

> Output

```
                       Text                      clean text
0       I am feeling good !           I am feeling good تعج
1  I am testing this code ؟  I am testing this code استفهام
```